# KVM Through Patch Panels

Tags: patch-management, keyboard-video-mouse

I'm planning to add patch panels to our data center.
We have around 30 machines connected directly to our switch today, and it's getting messy.

The original installation was based on broadcast infrastructures where patch panels aren't used (I have no idea why).

**Should I add patch panels to KVM cables as well, since most of our machines are accessed through extenders?**

Objectives:

1. Better/cleaner installation
2. Possibility to quickly replace a broken client machine

Comment: Do the machines have IPMI on them?  if so, they usually come with an iKVM built in.  It means you just need to wire for ethernet and use any machine on the LAN to access them potentially remotely.  It's a lot less cables and a lot more convenient.

Comment: @Matt: if he's using extenders that have RJ-45 connectors, switching to IPMI won't save him any cables. That said, your theory is sound; assuming separation of networks exists, the servers support it and they're licenced for the advanced features.

Comment: @Matt No, they do not. Also, I should have mentioned that they're running [Avid Media Composer](http://www.avid.com/US/products/media-composer#overview), so we're extending a second monitor output from each machine (Thanks for the info on IPMI, by the way).

Comment: @GregL - maybe things have changed in this arena?  I haven't used the old style KVM switch products in years.  You used to need a 3 cables for keyboard/mouse and monitor instead of 1 ethernet cable IPMI/iKVM.  Anyway, looks like he doesn't have IPMI available

Comment: @GregL Yeah, most of the machines are clients. There are around 10 servers, only accessed by me (usually through remote desktop or SSH).

Comment: IPMI isn't a KVM per-se but rather a remote management platform for server-class hardware. What I was talking about was what most current datacenter style KVMs use, which are little dongles to interface the server to the KVM. We use Raritan products, so we have the `D2CIM-DVUSB` [CIM](http://www.raritan.com/products/accessories/computer-interface-modules)s, and [these](http://www.raritan.com/products/kvm-switches/dominion-kxiii) KVMs to proivde that functionality, patched from each server cabinet to a central network cabinet that houses the KVM switch and monitor.